# Microsoft Face API- Find Similar face from Real Time Video

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am working on application which detect user faces and find similar faces from Realtime live streaming video using Microsoft Cognitive Services- Face API.I am using following example for my reference:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis/tree/master/Windows/LiveCameraSample

I am able to detect faces from real time video but I am not getting any idea how to store face images and how to detect similar faces from it.

Can anyone please help to find the way?

Answer (score 2):

Your are looking for an other existing feature of Face API. It is a combination of several operations:

- Initiate your project by creating a `Person Group`
- Use `Detect` to find faces in images
- Use `Find Similar` to check if a face is already existing in a person group
- For new faces, create a person and store in the person group the newly created persons and associated faces

Face API documentation: [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)

But in fact, there is an open-source demo project from Microsoft called **Intelligent-Kiosk** that has a demo called **Realtime Crowd Insights** that is doing exactly those things. The source code is on Github, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-IntelligentKiosk/blob/master/Documentation/RealtimeCrowdInsights.md).